# I cannot access other's facebook page insights though i connected through login pop up

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

i have create Facebook app for my external website and i created an Access token for that app with the "offline" access Permission (access token)  with that token, i placed the Login button in my site ,i'm trying to fetch the insights data's,of those who log in through my External website with Facebook while connect i'm passing the **offline_access, Manage_page** **read_insights** permission, though permission granted by the page Admins i'm difficult to fetch the insights datas.Please some one help me to figure this

```
aspx file

<fb:login-button scope="manage_pages,offline_access,read_insights" size="large" style="opacity:.01 !important; width:250px !important;line-height: 31px !important;margin-top:0 !important;" onlogin="getPages()"> Sign In With Facebook Account </fb:login-button></div>
```

scrpit file

```
window.getPages = function () {
    loadingImage($('#divSettings'), true, ($('.divSettings').outerHeight() - 50) + 'px');
    //test
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
       if (response.status.toString().indexOf("connected") > -1) {
            //User is conected and granded perms Good to go!
            // alert('1');
            FB.api('/me/accounts', function (resp) {
                //var txtpageid = document.getElementById('ctl00_contentPlaceHolderRight_txtFBPageID').value;
                var txtpageid = $.trim($('#ctl00_contentPlaceHolderRight_txtFBPageID').val());
                //  alert(2);
                $('#spnFBsignMo').removeClass('Dsh_pop_MessTxt Pop_Facebk_Txt_error').addClass('Dsh_pop_MessTxt Pop_Facebk_Txt');
                // if (response.error && response.error.type == "OAuthException") { alert('OAuth2.0 Exception Access token Expired or AppID miss matched'+'<br>'+'please contact Admin'); }
                if (txtpageid != '') {
                    FBactualID = '';
                    for (var i = 0, l = resp.data.length; i < l; i++) {
                        var page = resp.data[i];
                        if (page.id == txtpageid) {
                            FBactualID = txtpageid;
                            varFBResponseFlag = true;
                            //alert('inside the page id validation');
                        }
                    }
                }
                getCheckedValue(FBactualID);
                // alert('3');
            });
        }
        else {
            //measures to take the users to login again 
            // alert('You must login to Facebook to Validate the Page ID');
            $('#spnFBsignMo').removeClass('Dsh_pop_MessTxt Pop_Facebk_Txt').addClass('Dsh_pop_MessTxt Pop_Facebk_Txt_error'); //DSh_Input_cus DSh_Input_width
            loadingImage($('#divSettings'), false, ($('.divSettings').outerHeight() - 50) + 'px');
            alert(4);
        }
    }); // login sta
```

i'm just give a call to with my access token to fetch information

something like this

```
https://graph.facebook.com/246355928767490/insights/page_views&access_token=xxxxxx-xxx-xx&since=2011-12-25&untill=2012-01-04
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to

https://graph.facebook.com/app_id/insights

Will only give you access to insights about your app, not "other's facebook page insights". If you are actually trying to get your own insights, check first that there is any data by going to the insights page and looking at your specific application here:

http://www.facebook.com/insights/

If you are trying to get the visiting, logged in user's Insight stats for pages they own, there are already a number of answers to this. You will need to troubleshoot whether your user is indeed logged in or not but the function you are using to retrieve insights should be right. Have a look at theses previous answers:

[Facebook page insights via API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966666/facebook-page-insights-via-api)

[Facebook Insights for Page via the API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816156/facebook-insights-for-page-via-the-api)

Comment: actually i would like to get the users page insights not mine.

Comment: actually i would like to get the users page insights not mine. in the call i'm passing users page id not my appID. my question was, Is that possible to get insights data's of the user's page through my App access_token or i need get access_token along with permission, in my above code i try to access the data's keeping my access token commonly for all the user since i got permission while request for login. please let me know do i need to store access_token for all the user's individualy.

Comment: Edited my response, have a look.

Comment: i have gone through the links which are already i saw it while posting this question though its good to remember procedure. i found another way to get access_ token while login  just i added two line with above code..

Comment: FB.login(function (response) {
 if (response.authResponse) {
 var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
           alert('access_token' + accessToken); }  else {             console.log("user  accestoken not get");
     }   }); just i added this code below my init function thanks @Ramengo thanks for spending your valuable time for me.

Comment: No worries Chandru, I hope all goes well with your application.